# Remove Leading Spaces from a variable in Bash

Tags: bash, sed, spaces

I have a script that exports a XML file to my desktop and then extracts all the data in the "id" tags and exports that to a csv file.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//id[1]' -v . -n </users/$USER/Desktop/List.xml > /users/$USER/Desktop/List2.csv
```

I then use the following command to add commas after each number and store it as a variable.

```
 devices=$(sed "s/$/,/g" /users/$USER/Desktop/List2.csv)
```

If I echo that variable I get an output that looks like this:

```
123,
124,
125,
```

etc.

What I need help with is removing those spaces so that output will look like 123,124,125 with no leading space. I've tried multiple solutions that I can't get to work. Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want newlines, don't tell `xmlstarlet` to put them there in the first place.

That is, change `-n` to `-o ,` to put a comma after each value rather than a newline:

```
{ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//id[1]' -v . -o ',' && printf '\n'; } \
  <"/users/$USER/Desktop/List.xml" \
  >"/users/$USER/Desktop/List2.csv"
```

The `printf '\n'` here puts a final newline at the end of your CSV file after xmlstarlet has finished writing its output.

If you don't want the trailing `,` this leaves on the output file, the easiest way to be rid of it is to read the result of `xmlstarlet` into a variable and manipulate it there:

```
content=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//id[1]' -v . -o ',' <"/users/$USER/Desktop/List.xml")
printf '%s\n' "${content%,}" >"/users/$USER/Desktop/List2.csv"
```

Comment: Thank you! The second command is what I really needed. I didn't realize I was making such a stupid mistake :/

Answer (score 0):

For a sed solution, try

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;y/\n/,/' /users/$USER/Desktop/List2.csv
```

or if you want a comma even after the last:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;y/\n/,/;s/$/,/' /users/$USER/Desktop/List2.csv
```

but then more easy would be

```
cat /users/$USER/Desktop/List2.csv | tr "\n" ","
```

Comment: Thanks! That is actually super helpful, it removes that trailing very nicely :)